# Getting 404 errors for everything under wwwroot in a Blazor type library project

Tags: .net, blazor, http-status-code-404, blazor-webassembly, wwwroot

I've been working on this Blazor demo project which was originally in .Net Core 3.1. I updated it to .Net 5.0. After a while, I finally got it to build under 5.0, but started getting errors such as

```
The static web asset 'C:\Dev\VisualStudioProjects\BethanyPieShopBlazor\BethanysPieShopHRM.App\wwwroot\css\bootstrap\bootstrap.min.css' has a conflicting web root path '/wwwroot/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' with the project file 'wwwroot\css\bootstrap\bootstrap.min.css'.  BethanysPieShopHRM.Server   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.5_0.targets    209
```

I realized that this is probably because I have the wwwroot folder with static files both in the calling project and in the type library project that the calling project calls. Curiously, this wasn't an issue while all the projects were .Net Core 3.1, but it now is when it's all been converted to .Net 5.0.

I went and excluded the wwwroot folder from the calling project, thinking this one wasn't relevant, since it's the resources under wwwroot in the type library project that are being called anyway. But what really puzzles me here is that, when I go to the dev tools in Chrome and look at the console tab, none of the resources are being located, and I am getting http 404 errors for all the resources in the type library Blazor project. When I look at the actually path, I see this "_content" prefix that's the part of the name that doesn't exist in the VS IDE, so I figure it's a .Net runtime mechanism, but I am wondering whether that's something that has any bearing to what's going on.

Another thought I had was whether there was any special configuration work to be done if the wwwroot folder with all the static files is located in a type library project as opposed to the regular web project. I am thinking that what I am seeing at design time and what the path ends up being at runtime might be two different things, but I am not quite sure how to keep going about debugging this and how to proceed.

[image: 404 errors for everything under wwwroot]

This is what is under wwwroot in the Blazor type library project:

[image]

UPDATE:

Yes, thank you. I am running Blazor Server, and I just noticed that my obj and bin folders have been marked red, and this definitely looks like it's all a part of this issue. I will go ahead and delete those and retry

[image]

Comment: It looks like your running Blazor Server?  The content in any library referenced in web project with a `wwwroot` folder is available at the site address _content/libraryname/...   So having files with the same name isn't a problem as only the web site `wwwroot` gets mapped as the web site root.  All the libraries are in `_content/...`  You will get this problem in hosted WASM as both the web server and the WASM library `wwwroot` are mapped to the web site root.  I would delete all the `obj` and `bin` folders and re-build the projects

Comment: There is a WebAssembly project and a Blazor Server project, and each of them calls the type library project, where nearly all functionality is located. After I deleted the bin and obj folders in Blazor Server and type library projects, I did a build, and got this:
```The static web asset 'C:\Dev\VisualStudioProjects\BethanyPieShopBlazor\BethanysPieShopHRM.App\wwwroot\css\bootstrap\bootstrap.min.css' has a conflicting web root path '/wwwroot/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' with the project file 'wwwroot\css\bootstrap\bootstrap.min.css'. BethanysPieShopHRM.Server
```

Comment: As I can't see your actual solution structure I'm guessing that the conflict is between the Web Assembly project and the web project that hosts the Web Assembly.  You can't have duplicate files in each of these.  If you're still unsure post a image of your solution structure with the `wwwroot` directories and project dependancies expanded.

Comment: @Ivan, it'd be nice if you provide closure - this is what makes SO valuable.

Comment: G. Stoynev, the Pluralsight author whose modified example I've been using here has updated his codebase to .Net Core 6.0. I've decided to shelve this particular issue for the time-being, as I have his 6.0 Blazor code to work with and no longer need to upgrade. I think I will eventually return to trying to understand some of these version-specific discrepancies, but I feel like I need to get more Blazor knowledge under my belt before navigating these waters once again.